# Images temporarily reloading with other images when moving flutter map

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, fluttermap

I'm using Firebase to load images onto a Flutter Map as CircleAvatar with CachedNetworkImage. The problem is that the images "dance" around or reload other images when I move the map around. I don't understand why other images will sometimes show in the spot where the image loads at. This is more obvious on mobile browser than on a desktop. How do I make it so that if the images need to be redrawn that they don't temporarily load another image into it for what is a microsecond. I don't understand if the cause of this is how I have my firebase query written or if this is a problem with the way the image values are stored in flutter. Example page and code linked below. What do I do to stop the images from doing this flickering or reloading?

My example page is linked [here](https://rideyrbike.com/test/#/).

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import "package:latlong2/latlong.dart";

class CustomMarker extends StatefulWidget {
  final double? latitude;
  final double? longitude;

  CustomMarker({this.latitude, this.longitude});

  @override
  _MapsPageState createState() => _MapsPageState();
}

class _MapsPageState extends State<CustomMarker> {
  List<Marker> list = [];
  List<String> listDocuments = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setMarkers();
  }

  void setMarkers() async {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference =
        firestore.collection('wllmtnnstpphotos');
    collectionReference.snapshots().listen((event) {
      List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots = event.docs;
      for (var map in snapshots) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data =
            map.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; // add this line
        MarkerCollectModelPhoto model =
            MarkerCollectModelPhoto.fromMap(data); // use data here
        String nameDocument = map.id;
        listDocuments.add(nameDocument);
        Marker marker = customMarker(model, nameDocument);
        setState(() {
          list.add(marker);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  Marker customMarker(
      MarkerCollectModelPhoto markerCollectModelPhoto, String nameDocument) {
    return Marker(
      width: 30.0,
      height: 30.0,
      point: LatLng(markerCollectModelPhoto.lat!, markerCollectModelPhoto.lng!),
      builder: (ctx) => InkWell(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            foregroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                markerCollectModelPhoto.pathImageSmall!),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            maxRadius: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FlutterMap(
      options: new MapOptions(
          center: LatLng(44.8004173, -122.8543808), minZoom: 1.0, zoom: 8.5),
      layers: [
        new TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
        MarkerLayerOptions(
          markers: list,
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class MarkerCollectModelPhoto {
  double? lat, lng;
  String? name, pathImage, pathImageSmall, dateTime, uid, mileager;

  MarkerCollectModelPhoto(
      {this.lat,
      this.lng,
      this.name,
      this.pathImage,
      this.pathImageSmall,
      this.dateTime,
      this.mileager,
      this.uid});

  MarkerCollectModelPhoto.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    lat = map['Lat'];
    lng = map['Lng'];
    name = map['Racer'];
    pathImage = map['PathImage'];
    pathImageSmall = map['PathImageSmall'];
    dateTime = map['DateTime'];
    mileager = map['mileager'];
    uid = map['Uid'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that Flutter is reusing your markers incorrectly. If you give them a unique key, Flutter won't reuse/rebuild them needlessly.

Try adding a UniqueKey() like this.

```
 return Marker(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      width: 30.0,
      height: 30.0,
```

Comment: Ah this is brilliant, I swore I had seen this somewhere in my searches but failed to understand how simple it was. Thank you so much.

Comment: What happens, especially when you provide a list of similar things, is that Flutter will reuse or rebuild (I'm not sure which) the Widgets in the list. What you were seeing was the previous rebuild's contents which was then overwritten by the correct contents. By supplying a UniqueKey(), Flutter can make optimizations based on knowing that a Widget is the same one as a previous layout pass. This has the nice side effect of making the frame construction slightly faster since Flutter can now re-use previously created objects.

Comment: Noted, this helps the page load times immensely, thanks again.